# Unwanted excel add-in loads but no trace of it anywhere

Tags: excel, add-in

When loading Excel2013, an old add-in continues appearing in the tabs, although not requested

The add-in does not appear in VBA projects nor in any file in Office or Users folders

The add-in does not show in Excel options add-ins list

I wonder from where Excel loads it and looks for a way to get rid of it

Thanks

Avi

Answer (score 0):

If this is a "phantom toolbar/menu" appearing in the addins tab you can remove it by right-clicking it and choosing delete.

Also make sure you have checked the COM addins list as well as the Excel addins list.